# Connect IPcamera(DCS-930L) to a third party C# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, video, video-streaming, ip-camera

I would like to develop a WPF application where I can view the live stream from my DCS-930L camera..With this WPF application, I must be able to control the zoom of my IPcam too..
Besides that, is DCS-930L using RTSP or Onvif ?How can I verify this ?
Im very new to this IPcam topic, in fact I just started working on it yesterday. So I found this Ozeki WPF application:

> http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_36-how-to-connect-to-an-rtsp-camera-and-display-the-picture-using-wpf.html

P.S : you are welcome to recommend me any other C# WPF samples instead of the above.
Lets assume my username and password for my Dlink account is (**"123@gmail.com","testpassword"**).Im trying to connect my camera to this application but Im not sure how to I fill up the following line:

```
_camera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera("rtsp://192.168.115.175:554/12", "admin", "admin");
```

Here is the complete code:

```
using System.Windows;
using Ozeki.Media.IPCamera;
using Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers;
using Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers.Video;

namespace Camera_Viewer_Connect_RTSP_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private IIPCamera _camera;
        private BitmapSourceProvider _bitmapSourceProvider;
        private MediaConnector _connector;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _bitmapSourceProvider = new BitmapSourceProvider();
            _connector = new MediaConnector();
            videoViewer.SetImageProvider(_bitmapSourceProvider);
        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _camera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera("rtsp://192.168.115.175:554/12", "admin", "admin");
            _connector.Connect(_camera.VideoChannel, _bitmapSourceProvider);
            _camera.Start();
            videoViewer.Start();          
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_162-how-to-connect-to-your-d-link-ip-camera-onvif.html maybe this might help and try using one of the url from the list in your browser and see if you get any feed from the camera as a first step..


http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112710/C-VB-NET-Camera-Communication-Libraries this is a another sample project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Of all DCS -930L camera does not support Onvif or RTSP Protocol it uses HTTP ...You can't use DCS 930L in this situation.You need a RTSP or Onvif compliant camera for that.
And on the other hand What ever Camera (Ozeki SDK) library you are using, i don't know whether it is the best or not  but I can tell you till now it is most flexible solution for developers.